# Undefined Result for Variable with Javascript innerHTML function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing some code for a prototype banking website and am having a problem carrying some math into the HTML text.  As shown below, the three numerical values I am wanting to show up are instead returning "undefined."  These undefined items should be 22.69, 972.69, and 972.69 respectively.

[image]

Can someone explain why this is happening and suggest a potential solution?

Here is my JS / HTML:

```js
document.getElementById("lad").innerHTML = lineAmountDue;
document.getElementById("lcb").innerHTML = lineCurrentBalance;
document.getElementById("lbb").innerHTML = lineBeginningBalance;

var lineAmountDue = "Amount Due = " + varAmountDue;
var lineCurrentBalance = "Current Balance = " + varCurrentBalance;
var lineBeginningBalance = "Beginning Balance = " + varBeginningBalance;

var varAmountDue = 22.69;
var varCurrentBalance = 972.69;
var varBeginningBalance = 972.69;

pn_btn.onclick = function() {
    varCurrentBalance = varCurrentBalance - varAmountDue;
 varAmountDue = varAmountDue*0;
};

lf_btn.onclick = function() {
 var load_value = prompt("How much money do you want to load?", "10");
 var num1 = parseFloat(load_value);
 if (load_value != null) {
      varCurrentBalance = varCurrentBalance + num1;
  }
}
```

```css
table, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
 

th {
    text-align: left;
 background-color: #1D4E86;
    color: white;
}

td {
    text-align: left;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
}


div.bold_font {
 font-weight: bold; 
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}

p {
  color: black;
}

.container {width:900px;
      margin:5px auto 5px auto;
      padding:5px;}
   

#white_font {
 color:white;
 }

head {
 background-color: #F47C20;
}

html {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- img src="Logo_pic.png" text-align="left" width="900" -->

</head>
<body bgcolor="#D3D1D2">

 <div style="width:100%;"> 
Account Details
<br>

<!--This is the left column -->

<div style="float:left; width:50%;">

<img src="Graph.png"text-align="left" height="300">

</div>

<!--This is the right column -->

<div style="float:right; width:50%; ">

 <!--This is the "Pay Now" button -->
 
 <h1 style=font-family:Arial;text-left;size:14pt;color:#FFFFFF;>

</h1 style=color:black>

<p id="lad"></p>
<p id="lcb"></p>
<p id="lbb"></p>

<input type="button" id="pn_btn" value="Pay Now" />
<input type="button" id="lf_btn" value="Load Funds" />

<br>
<br>

Transactions this Month

<table style="width:90%">
  <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Recipient</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
 </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Crif Dogs</td>
    <td>December 5, 2015</td>
    <td>$4.56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tony's Pizza</td>
    <td>December 6, 2015</td>
    <td>$10.57</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Xian's Famous Foods</td>
 <td>December 7, 2015</td>
 <td>$7.56</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> 
<br>
<br>
 
</div>
 
</div>



<script src="java_v2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?   I'm unfamiliar with the error and relatively new to JS.  Thank you all for your help - I genuinely appreciate it.

Comment: Well you're using the variables before you assign values to them.

Comment: Read up on JavaScript hoisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining you items in the wrong order, JavaScript executes sequentially line by line (*top-down*). You will want to define the items you use first before assigning them with `.innerHTML`

```js
var varAmountDue = 22.69;
var varCurrentBalance = 972.69;
var varBeginningBalance = 972.69;

var lineAmountDue = "Amount Due = " + varAmountDue;
var lineCurrentBalance = "Current Balance = " + varCurrentBalance;
var lineBeginningBalance = "Beginning Balance = " + varBeginningBalance;

document.getElementById("lad").innerHTML = lineAmountDue;
document.getElementById("lcb").innerHTML = lineCurrentBalance;
document.getElementById("lbb").innerHTML = lineBeginningBalance;



pn_btn.onclick = function() {
    varCurrentBalance = varCurrentBalance - varAmountDue;
 varAmountDue = varAmountDue*0;
};

lf_btn.onclick = function() {
 var load_value = prompt("How much money do you want to load?", "10");
 var num1 = parseFloat(load_value);
 if (load_value != null) {
      varCurrentBalance = varCurrentBalance + num1;
  }
}
```

```css
table, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
 

th {
    text-align: left;
 background-color: #1D4E86;
    color: white;
}

td {
    text-align: left;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
}


div.bold_font {
 font-weight: bold; 
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}

p {
  color: black;
}

.container {width:900px;
      margin:5px auto 5px auto;
      padding:5px;}
   

#white_font {
 color:white;
 }

head {
 background-color: #F47C20;
}

html {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- img src="Logo_pic.png" text-align="left" width="900" -->

</head>
<body bgcolor="#D3D1D2">

 <div style="width:100%;"> 
Account Details
<br>

<!--This is the left column -->

<div style="float:left; width:50%;">

<img src="Graph.png"text-align="left" height="300">

</div>

<!--This is the right column -->

<div style="float:right; width:50%; ">

 <!--This is the "Pay Now" button -->
 
 <h1 style=font-family:Arial;text-left;size:14pt;color:#FFFFFF;>

</h1 style=color:black>

<p id="lad"></p>
<p id="lcb"></p>
<p id="lbb"></p>

<input type="button" id="pn_btn" value="Pay Now" />
<input type="button" id="lf_btn" value="Load Funds" />

<br>
<br>

Transactions this Month

<table style="width:90%">
  <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Recipient</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
 </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Crif Dogs</td>
    <td>December 5, 2015</td>
    <td>$4.56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tony's Pizza</td>
    <td>December 6, 2015</td>
    <td>$10.57</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Xian's Famous Foods</td>
 <td>December 7, 2015</td>
 <td>$7.56</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> 
<br>
<br>
 
</div>
 
</div>



<script src="java_v2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to javascript and wasn't aware of that rule.   As a follow-up, any thoughts on how I can make the two btn.onclick functions update the innerHTML amounts?   Those still aren't updating the values when the button is clicked.  I really appreciate your help, and thanks again for the input.

Comment: @AME You will want to have a `innerHTML` assignment in those functions.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've dropped in the innerHTML function and am now getting a NaN error.  It's basically just a recitation of the previous code, so not sure why that's happening.  Any clue what might be causing it? 

`pn_btn.onclick = function() {
    var varCurrentBalance = varCurrentBalance - varAmountDue;
 var varAmountDue = varAmountDue * 0;
 var lineAmountDue = "Amount Due = " + varAmountDue;
 var lineCurrentBalance = "Current Balance = " + varCurrentBalance;
 document.getElementById("lad").innerHTML = lineAmountDue;
 document.getElementById("lcb").innerHTML = lineCurrentBalance;
};`

Comment: @AME Remove the `var`'s, that means you are defining them to be new local variables inside the function. This actually creates a problem between what variables to use. For example, because you have a `var varAmountDue` on the second line JS is thinking you are meaning to use the local variable rather than the global variable on the next line when you do `varCurrentBalance - varAmountDue`. So `varAmountDue` is `undefined`. Basically, try and avoid local variables with the same name as globals.

Comment: Great, that worked!  Thanks for all your help.  Happy Holidays.